# Failure to find the jar file on nexus repository, was cashed in the local repository

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have faced with a next problem:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (default) on project mdw: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2 in **Here nexus url** was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of eict-plugins has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (default) on project mdw: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2 in **Here nexus url** was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of eict-plugins has elapsed or updates are forced
```

when maven building my project.

How can it be resolved, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried looking and could not find an oracle version of ojdbc7. Could you try with the below and see if this helps.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.noraui</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am co-creator of com.github.noraui, this jar file is deprecated, please use this sample: https://github.com/sgrillon14/MavenSampleOracleJdbc

Answer (score 0):

This artefact is available only on Oracle repository , to let maven download it you must declare the Oracle repository in your pom.xml :

```
    <dependencies>
.............
      <dependecy>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId> 
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId> 
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
      <dependency>
.............
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
        <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

You must have an Oracle account to be authenticated for the download, add this in  of your settings.xml file :

```
<server>
<id>maven.oracle.com</id>
<username>your_oracle_username</username>
<password>your_oracle_password</password>
<configuration>
  <basicAuthScope>
    <host>ANY</host>
    <port>ANY</port>
    <realm>OAM 11g</realm>
  </basicAuthScope>
  <httpConfiguration>
    <all>
      <params>
        <property>
          <name>http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects</name>
          <value>%b,true</value>
        </property>
      </params>
    </all>
  </httpConfiguration>
</configuration>
```